# AWS CLI - Create s3 bucket from Linux error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli, serverless-application-model

I'm using **AWS CLI** to create the **S3 bucket**.
I have installed the **AWS CLI** and running following command to create the bucket

```
aws s3 mb s3://Test-sam-bucket --region us-west-1
```

> > Error: 
> >     make_bucket failed: s3://Test-sam-bucket An error occurred (InvalidBucketName) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The specified bucket is not valid.

also, I have tried with:

```
aws s3 mb s3://sambucket --region us-west-1
```

> > Error:
> >     make_bucket failed: s3://sambucket An error occurred (BucketAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.

What am I doing wrong please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the first point where you are taking **Test-sam-bucket** name:

- do not use any special character between the bucket name, simply use **testsambucket** that would surely work with you.

Regarding your second point where you are getting the BucketAlreadyExists message:

- It is because the **S3 bucket** name is global namespace in **S3** shared by another **S3** user as well. Therefore, it has been unique at the global level.
- You can try with your own custom unique names like some combination of your teamName+BucketName or something else.
- The issue with Test-sam-bucket is that the first character can not be an upper case in bucket name, it can either be a lower case character or number. We can have hyphens in bucket names. More details about the restrictions can be found here: [docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)